# C# LINQ value substitution

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables with the following layout

```
 username | displayname            username| FirstName | surname
 ---------|------------            -----------------------------
 foo        test                    foo    | andrew    | blah
 fa         display
```

What I'm trying to do is display all of the `displayname` entries in the left hand table on my page. However, if there is a match on the `username` in the right hand table, I want the value `test` to be replaced by `andrew`.

Example out:

```
 username | displayname    
 ---------|------------      
 foo        andrew                    
 fa         display
```

Everything is a string.

Below is my attempt at what I need but I've messed it up as its applying the `firstname` value to every entry in my first table.

```
_users = UserService.GetAll().ToList();
_updates = UserUpdateService.GetAll().ToList();

foreach (var user in _users)
{
    foreach (var update in _updates)
        if (user.FirstName != "" && user.UserName == update.UserName)
        {
            update.DisplayName = user.FirstName;
        }
        else
        {
            update.DisplayName = user.UserName;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a single LINQ query?

Comment: as you literally mentioned the Q in LINQ stands for **query**, not **modify**. Thus what you want to achieve is not possible - or only with dirty hacks.

Comment: Your code looks pretty fine to me. LINQing it won´t give you any benefit, in fact it will most likely make your code uglier.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the issue is if I have a second entry in the other table and 'john' was the firstname value, then 'john' is applied to every display name value in the first table

Comment: That has nothing to do with if or if not to use LINQ, but with your business-logic. LINQ is just syntactic sugar, it adds absoluetely no **behaviour** to your code. So if you can´t do ith with a classic loop, you can´t do it with LINQ neither.

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you show me the correct logic for achieving what I need?

Comment: seems like you want to **join** on `username`.

Comment: I'd turn the second table into a dictionary to do the lookup on with `ToDictionary(x => x.username, x => x.FirstName)` then you can user `TryGetValue` to see if there is a matching username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @HimBromBeere which I also agree that ---  LINQ is just syntactic sugar, it adds absoluetely no behaviour to your code.

As to write different style of writing you can use the below code which uses few `Linq` operators

```
_users = UserService.GetAll().ToList();
_updates = UserUpdateService.GetAll().ToList();
_updates.ForEach(u => 
{
    var record == _users.FirstOrDefault(us => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(us.FirstName) && string.Equals(us.UserName, u.UserName));
    u.DisplayName = record != null ? record.FirstName : u.DisplayName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't be exactly as you posted, because we are going to be creating new instances instead of modifying existing ones, but you can do this query:

```
var table = _users
  .Select(user => new {
    user.UserName,
    DisplayName = _updates.Any(update => 
       user.FirstName != "" && user.UserName == update.UserName) 
    ?  user.FirstName 
    :  user.UserName 
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ordinal LINQ query with LEFT JOIN, don't try to do that with lists.

```cs
var users = UserService.GetAll();
var updates = UserUpdateService.GetAll();

var query = 
  from update in updates
  join user in users on user.UserName equals update.UserName into gj
  from user in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new 
  {
     update.UserName,
     DisplayName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName) ? user.FirstName : update.DisplayName
  };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't update anything it creates new anonymous objects.

Comment: @juharr. Read OP, he is trying to display data, not update. Why you fallback to objects, I don't know.